# How does the alternate primary stat for a class effect the overall stats?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

What does cunning do for a trooper or bounty hunter, or willpower on a warrior or knight, and vise versa?

EX: If I applied all cunning gear to my commando, how would that effect his combat efficiency?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because all classes now use the same mainstat, Mastery (introduced in 4.0) and so this mechanic no longer exists.

Comment: So they removed cunning, willpower, ect.?

Comment: Yes, exactly it.

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [What should be done with out of version questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5727/4797) and [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7235/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only affects special critical chance and bonus damage (in the same way that it would if it were mainstat).

So, for example, Cunning will give a Trooper or Bounty Hunter extra damage and crit chance for Tech attacks.

This is *very* minor and is by no means an alternative primary stat.  Getting datacrons will have a small beneficial effect, but trading other stats in gear for this "offstat" would be a mistake.